# Ansible read multiple variables with same name from vars_file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

In my `~/ip_vars_file` , I have

```
ip : 10.20.30
ip : 10.20.31
ip : 10.20.32
```

This is created with lineinfile,

```
lineinfile: line="ip{{':'}} {{item.public_ip}}"
              dest="{{ansible_env.HOME}}/ip_vars_file}}"
with_items: servers.tagged_instances #servers is registered in previous task
```

I am unable to read all three ips as with_items. I get only the last IP in my playbook.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: print ips
    debug:
      var: item 
    with_items: "{{ ip }}"

  vars_files:
  - ~/ip_vars_file
```

The output I am getting is,

```
TASK [print ips] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.20.32) => {
    "item": "10.20.32"
}
```

The output I want is something like this

```
TASK [print ips] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=10.20.32) => {
    "item": "10.20.30"
    "item": "10.20.31"
    "item": "10.20.32"
}
```

I want to iterate over the ips one by one. How do I achieve this?

Basically, I want to store the ips of instances when launching and use them later during deployment. But I am stuck when I launch multiple instances with same name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to define a list:

```
---
ip:
  - 10.20.30
  - 10.20.31
  - 10.20.32
```

Comment: I am creating the file using ansible lineinfile ,  so I cannot change the way I define that file.

Comment: I edited the question. Basically, I want to store the ips of instances when launching and use them later during deployment. But I am stuck when I launch multiple instances with same name.

Comment: Use a Jinja2 template and save it as a list as in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @techraf, I am storing the ips to the file as a list.