# Grep vars from a file with ansible to use later in a task with a for loop

Tags: shell, ansible

I am relatively new to ansible.

I have a `parameters.yml` with something like this:

```
parameters: 
  stuff: bullshit
  otherstuff: otherbullshit
  domain_locale: domain.locale.test
  domain_differentlocale1: domain.differentlocale1.test
  domain_differentlocale2: domain.differentlocale2.test
  domain_differentlocale3: domain.differentlocale3.test
  uninteresting_stuff: uninteresting_bullshit
```

This file is in another directory, but I could also symlink it to be in defaults/main.yml. Doesn't matter.

What I would like to accomplish is grep somehow within an ansible task these `domain.*.test` values and use it as vars in another task with ansible. This other task would be to write it directly after `127.0.0.1 localhost` in the same line in the `/etc/hosts`.

I am not even sure which of the modules to use in ansible. `include_vars` has no additional grep as I see it. `set_fact` does not read from a different file(can I combine it with a shell command? how?). `lineinfile` does not have a source and dest, so it is also limited to one file.

I also thought this post would help me: [Ansible read multiple variables with same name from vars_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656563/ansible-read-multiple-variables-with-same-name-from-vars-file)
but it does not need the grep part, I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    parameters:
      stuff: bullshit
      otherstuff: otherbullshit
      domain_locale: domain.locale.test
      domain_differentlocale1: domain.differentlocale1.test
      domain_differentlocale2: domain.differentlocale2.test
      domain_differentlocale3: domain.differentlocale3.test
      uninteresting_stuff: uninteresting_bullshit
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/test.txt
        regexp: ^127.0.0.1
        line: "127.0.0.1 localhost {{ parameters.values() | select('match','domain.*test') | list | join(' ') }}"
```

Comment: I get: 

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "<generator object _select_or_reject at 0x7f5e8225b730>"
}

Comment: do you print is with `debug`? you need explicit `list` conversion in this case, i've added it to my answer for clarity.

Comment: So I tried it with a separate file with one key: value pair in it, there it works no prob, YAY.  But when I try the parameters.yml, which I can also debug, I still get {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ parameters.values() | select(\"match\", \"value\") | list }}): expected string or buffer"}

where "value" is a simple value in the second line of the file.

Thank you very much so far :)

Ah I see in another of your posts, this means msg is undefined. Damn, but why?

Comment: if `parameters` dict may have non-string items, you should select strings first with `select('string')` because `match` test expects all items to be strings.

Comment: Almost everything works, except replacing the line in the file. So thank you very much for helping and teaching me!